# GWT unit testing with cookies

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, cookies

I would like to unit test a GWT project with cookies. I'm currently unit testing the authentication part of the code. So I need to be able to store a sessionID as a cookie and retrieve it later. I'm currently using a normal TestCase (not GWTTestCase) with SyncProxy to test the asynchronous behaviour.

The problem is that nor the SyncProxy, nor the Unit Test behave as a browser and support the management of cookies. Any ideas how I can test this?

To be complete, when trying to test, I get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies.uriEncode(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies.uriEncode(Native Method)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies.setCookie(Cookies.java:177)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies.setCookie(Cookies.java:158)
    at com.projects.client.Authentication.setSesssionCookie(Authentication.java:64)
    at com.projects.client.Authentication$signInCredentialsHandler.onSuccess(Authentication.java:96)
    at com.projects.client.Authentication$signInCredentialsHandler.onSuccess(Authentication.java:1)
    at com.gdevelop.gwt.syncrpc.RemoteServiceInvocationHandler$1.run(RemoteServiceInvocationHandler.java:175)
```

Comment: Is using Selenium testing out of scope for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SSR told, cookies are already tested, Why do you need to test it again??. I believe you want an **cookie string** so that you can unit test your method. If that is the case, try **mocking that method and return whatever string you want** or you can **ignore the method call**.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't consider mocking.
The link you gave isn't working.
The wiki has a nice article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

Answer (score 1):

Cookie Unit Test approach

1) GWT unit testing for Cookie http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/test/com/google/gwt/user/client/CookieTest.java

2) It is not really clear why you need to test GWT code which is already unit tested. If your scenario is integration test then Selenium based browser test cases are the best bet.

3) Use mocking libraries or test utilities like http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/

I would not recommend third approach. If your unit testing get complicated then your code is complicated or the scenario is wrong.

Comment: The problem is that I want to test the signIn and signOut of the authentication class. But when I test those methods cookies are being set, retrieved,..hence the error I posted.

Should I be working with a TESTING flag, store the sessionID somewhere or something else? I don't like both options, they don't keep the code clean.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing, this code is working in my environment.
You can get the sessionid from cookie.

```
CookieManager cookiemanager = LoginUtils.loginFormBasedJ2EE("hostname", "username", "password");

                    SyncProxy.setBaseURL("baseURI");



                    StandardDispatchService rpcService =  SyncProxy.createProxy(StandardDispatchService.class,
                            new ProxySettings().setCookieManager(cookiemanager));

                    System.out.println(cookiemanager.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0));
                    String JSESSIONID = cookiemanager.getCookieStore().getCookies().get(0).getValue();

                    rpcService.execute(new XXXAction(XXX,XX));
```